# slow query infinitescroll respond on tumblr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm using this code which I found was faster than the one I used to have:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(window).load(function(){
> var $wall = $('.posts');
> $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
> $wall.masonry({
> itemSelector: '.entry',
> isAnimated : false
> });
> });
>
> $wall.infinitescroll({
> navSelector : "div#navigation",
> nextSelector : "div#navigation a#nextPage",
> itemSelector : ".entry",
> bufferPx : 2000,
> debug : false,
> errorCallback: function() {
> $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
> }},
> function( newElements ) {
> var $newElems = $( newElements );
> $newElems.hide();
> $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
> $wall.masonry( 'appended', $newElems,{isAnimated: false}, function(){$newElems.fadeIn('slow');} );
> });
> }); $('.posts').show(500);
> });
> </script> <script>
> $.fn.changebackgroundColor = function(msg) {
> $("#perma").css("#000");   }; </script>
> ```

But it's still rather slow, there is a delay for the posts to load and I wondered what is it that I could change. I use 3 columns with about 1100px large in total.

Comment: It really helps if you format/indent your scripts when posting them.  If your editor doesn't have a nice reformat tool, you can use http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: the issue is probably related to the `bufferPx` property.

```
             bufferPx     : 40,
             // increase this number if you want infscroll to fire quicker
             // (a high number means a user will not see the loading message)
             // new in 1.2
             // default: 40
```

If adjusting that value doesn't have a noticeable impact, it could just be the loading time, depending on how much data is being loaded.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. I tried to raise the number but it didn't change anything, I guess it's the usual loading time. Can you perhaps link me to the document you used? Thanks again.